# Getting results of a javascript from a web page

Tags: javascript, html, matlab

First of all, I am unfamiliar with JavaScript.

This is the web page I am trying to get results from: http://quepy.machinalis.com/

There is a "Ask a question" section and after asking a question, it briefly waits for loading "Get a query" section in the web page. After loading time, it shows the query translation of my natural language input. This query is what I want to get by using `urlread` function of Matlab or any other way. By looking at page source, I cannot find that query and the web page uses main.js to fill that section I pressume. I can see the javascript function/methods but have no idea how to run them.

Is it possible to get those results by simply using `urlread` function of Matlab? What would be my other options within Matlab?

Comment: Have you tried http://quepy.machinalis.com/#What%20is%20the%20capital%20of%20Bolivia?

Comment: Yes, I did try it. The HTML web content of that URL does not include the content in "Get a query" section as you see in web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using chrome or firefox, hit f12 and look at the browser developer tools there is a network tab. If you make a query you can see what request is being made. In this case it's a GET request to `http://quepy.machinalis.com/engine/get_query?question=`. 
 
If you for instance make the request "What is the time in England?" The query made is: http://quepy.machinalis.com/engine/get_query?question=What+is+the+time+in+England
You can then click on the preview or response tab and see the actual data object returned by the site.

Comment: OP wants a MATLAB way, see the last sentence in his question. How'd one go about implementing this in MATLAB?

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your help! I can call whatever function I see in main.js in this way I pressume?

Comment: URL request with that link will return me what I want, so it is good for me. @Adriaan

Comment: You should be able to discover the correct url to construct using this method. For instance the call to the Freebase answer is actually `https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=%5B%7B%0A++++%22%2Flocation%2Fcountry%2Fcapital%22%3A+%5B%7B%0A++++++++%22%2Ftype%2Fobject%2Fname%22%3A+%5B%7B%7D%5D%0A++++%7D%5D%2C%0A++++%22%2Ftype%2Fobject%2Fname~%3D%22%3A+%22England%22%2C%0A++++%22%2Ftype%2Fobject%2Ftype%22%3A+%22%2Flocation%2Fcountry%22%0A%7D%5D` so that function is a bit more complex